# converting html+js to exe

Tags: javascript, html, executable

I have an HTML file with embedded Javascript, and I want to convert it to a stand-alone exe.

Is that possible? How can I do it? Any html2exe tool out there?

P.S. If you must ask why, it's a very simple text-processing utility, but certain people want it (for reasons beyond me) as a desktop application.

Answer (score 7):

Try this open-source app **Node-webkit** (from here https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) powered by Chromium JS engine and Node.js. You can pack the Node-webkit app package to a standalone .exe file. Please go through the documentation provided in the page. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps

Read the Node.js documentation http://nodejs.org/api/ and see how powerful the API is! Node-webkit provides additional API to make app menubar, use system tray icon and post notifications etc and to make the application more native! Fortunately, Node-webkit is cross-platform so you can easily port apps to Linux and Mac OS X!

I strongly recommend you to use Node-webkit to make powerful desktop apps in HTML5 CSS3 and JavaScript. All the best! :)

Here are some examples : StormCloud, NitroTasks etc.. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-node-webkit

Answer (score 5):

They don't generate an exe but you may be interested in looking into [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/it/products/air/) and its opensource rival [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com)

Answer (score 4):

If your desktops are limited to Windows have you considered creating it as a [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx)?

You get the ability to launch from the desktop with out the need to create an EXE.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to Run a single HTML web Page as an application / Exe , Please try the following methods.

1) Rename the .html page to .hta

2) Add the following code sniplet to your html pages  tag.

```
<HEAD>
<HTA:Application
 Border = Thick
 BorderStyle = Complex
 ShowInTaskBar = No
 MaximizeButton = No
 MinimizeButton = No
>
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how complex the page is.

If it's a one pager, would a .hta work for you?

If it's multiple pages, you could use the IE [Webbrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control (or [geckofx](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) ) and a [HTTPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx)

Or you could [host the asp.net runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/community/columns/desmet/hostaspnet1.mspx) yourself.

In the past I've had success with the Webbrowser and injecting the HTML "by hand" (including all required scripts), but I wouldn't recommend it. It was a teeth grinding debugging nightmare. I kept going because it was "fun" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article explaining how to use a compiler from Micorosft.  It's not exactly what you want, but it's a start, so I figured I would post it:

http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/

It won't parse the HTML to make a GUI, but at least you can modify the JS code a little to compile, and then build a new UI on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scriptonit

It's my product for this very purpose: **js+html+css --> Windows EXE**

It can do a lot more than just process text; it lets you create real products. The only drawback is Edge behind the scenes, it was built on WebBrowser component. But with just one line of meta, Edge can and will behave like a proper HTML5 browser with CSS3. The magic line is included in the example below (the first line, actually).

###### Example: a textfile viewer

> Note: this is literally all it takes. You put this into a file named start.html and your app is working. It will display the contents of the file given as a first argument.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
<script src="../system/Scriptonit.Engine.js"></script>
<body>
    <pre> ... </pre>
</body>

<script>

    let sci = new ScriptonitInterface();         // initialize
    let args = sci.exeArguments().split("\n");   // take arguments
    let name = args[1]||"";                      // get 1st argument
    let text = sci.file.load(name);              // load file contents
    let disp = document.querySelector("pre");    // find <pre> tag
    disp.innerText = text;                       // display
    sci.window.setTitle(name);                   // set window title
    
</script>
```

[Scriptonit](https://scriptonit.dk) is free - it's a very lightweight Electron-like solution, dedicated to anyone looking for a way to make executables while still using the well-known html/js/css stack. Also, I'm trying to get happiness back to programming; it's really fun with this one. I promise.

Comment: Scriptonit uses MSHTML.dll and JSCRIPT9.dll (same as HTAs). The `content="IE=EDGE"` setting predates the existence of the Edge browser by many years and simply means "run MSHTML in the highest document mode available". Since the highest mode is 11, that setting is equivalent to `content="IE=11"`. The Edge browser (modern or legacy) does not come into play.

Comment: @LesFerch Thanks, now I know why. But the effect is, the browser will behave like Edge if it has this meta. If it's not there, the good old quirky IE will greet the passenger.

Comment: It will behave exactly like IE 11 with that declaration. If there's no declaration at all it will default to IE=5 mode. If there's only a DocType declaration, it will default to IE=7 mode. And the default can be changed (in some cases) by the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry setting. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358044/15764378).

Comment: You can add this code to any script to verify the document mode and user agent: `alert(document.documentMode + "\n\n" + window.navigator.userAgent);`

Answer (score 0):

Surely your desktop application is your browser ? Can you create a standalone .html file that contains the Javascript within it (rather than referenced via a separate URL/.js file). Plus the .css etc.

Then you can distribute that HTML file. Double-clicking it will launch it in the browser, and with no requirements on a remote server.