# javascript class in hta

Tags: javascript, jscript, hta

I am making a hta app for a home project and I would like to use javascript classes. Is this possible? If a use the basic example I find on google it gives a syntax error in hta. works as a html though. Also for my project I have to use hta as the UI and cant install anything.

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script>            
            resizeTo( 235, 246 );
            moveTo( screen.width/2-210, screen.height/2-250 );

            class Rectangle {
              constructor(height, width) {
                this.height = height;
                this.width = width;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>toolset</title>      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>some ui stuff</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Microsoft HTAs use a proprietary version of JavaScript based off ECMAScript Version 3 called JScript. The engine was never updated so you can only use features available in ECMAScript Version 3 and below. Modern JavaScript syntax will fail.

Comment: HTA is very outdated, [electronjs](https://www.electronjs.org/) may be something for you?

Comment: Also HTA is a thread, [read this](https://www.varonis.com/blog/living-off-the-land-lol-with-microsoft-part-ii-mshta-hta-and-ransomware).

Comment: @Kooilnc The described application doesn't introduce any threat. Electron is a lot more complicated and requires an install.

Comment: Don't be deterred. It's still OK to write HTA apps. For example, [this](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView/) and [this](https://lesferch.github.io/DesktopPic/). Exes have the advantage that they can be signed and there's a lower chance of AV false positives, but those are not big issues for non-commercial projects.

Comment: Be sure to set your HTA to run in IE 9 mode (or possibly IE 10 or IE 11 mode with caveats). By default, it will be running in IE 5 mode. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358044/15764378).