# BAT/HTA hybrid - How do I escape percent signs in the HTML section?

Tags: batch-file, hta

I am working on a [Batch/HTA hybrid file](https://github.com/bomeers/ACNH-Time-Travel/blob/main/ACNH-Time-Travel-v0.2.bat) and want to add some background music to the application. When I try to add a url (containing a percent sign) to a`<bgsound>` tag, it doesnt play anything. I got it working in [another application where the url didn't have any percent signs](https://github.com/bomeers/ACNH-Time-Travel/blob/main/badlands.bat).

```html
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
start "" mshta.exe "%~f0"
exit /b
-->


<html>
<head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL="no" SYSMENU="yes" >
    <title>ACNH - Time Travel Date Selection</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    window.resizeTo(1280, 720);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Testing audio...</h1>
    </div>
    <bgsound src="https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/animal-crossing-new-horizons-2020-switch-gamerip/pdjxvsymlc/3-02%20Get%20Ready%20for%20Your%20Flight%21.mp3">

</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding double percent signs to make batch ignore it but it made no difference. I'm not sure how to escape these characters in the html section

Comment: What happens if you change it to `<bgsound src="https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/animal-crossing-new-horizons-2020-switch-gamerip/pdjxvsymlc/3-02 Get Ready for Your Flight!.mp3">`

Comment: @razethestray no luck. Just silence

Comment: Please note that your HTA is missing any doctype or document mode declaration. Therefore, it's running in IE 5 mode. To put that in perspective, IE 5 was released in 1999. Please see "Further background information on HTA document modes" in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358044/15764378). In general, you're best bet is to run in IE 11 mode, but there are situations where running in an older mode may be desirable.

Comment: Also note that, unless you need to directly access the file system or registry, a web page, using a modern browser engine, makes more sense than an HTA. Also note that you can pass parameters to an HTA, so it may not be necessary to make a hybrid script.

Comment: @LesFerch I do need to access a file system so HTA hybrid is the way to go to keep this project as light as possible. The doctype and Mode declaration you were talking about was exactly my issue. I was defaulting to IE-5 and it wasn't using any updated html tags like <audio>

Comment: Cool. Is the reason for embedding a batch file so that you can run it in a console mode? If so, you can just parse the command line in the HTA and do everything in JScript.

Comment: @LesFerch Im having this script run before opening a game so it will change the epoch date being set in the games config files to whatever the end user sets before actually opening the game. I'm hoping there's a way to add controller support in some sense

Comment: @LesFerch here's the file I'm working on: 
https://github.com/bomeers/ACNH-Time-Travel/blob/main/ACNH-Time-Travel-v0.2.bat

Comment: you need `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />` . IE9 is the latest version of internet explorer that supports bgsound tag.

Comment: @npocmaka The `bgsound` tag works with all versions of IE, but not with the URL provided in the question (exact reason TBD). That point is now moot because the OP has moved on to using the `audio` tag in IE 11 mode.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [OJBakker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76902570/10082088):

> The bgsound tag is an Internet Explorer only tag, so this will not work in other browsers.

one inconsistent workaround was to use this instead:

```html
<embed src="https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/animal-crossing-new-horizons-2020-switch-gamerip/pdjxvsymlc/3-02%20Get%20Ready%20for%20Your%20Flight!.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false" width="0" height="0">
```

The final solution was found by LesFerch:

> Please note that your HTA is missing any doctype or document mode declaration. Therefore, it's running in IE 5 mode. To put that in perspective, IE 5 was released in 1999. Please see "Further background information on HTA document modes" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300218/sub-function-not-working-in-hta/70358044#70358044). In general, you're best bet is to run in IE 11 mode, but there are situations where running in an older mode may be desirable. –
> LesFerch

basically I was defaulting to IE-5. Adding this changes it to IE-11

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
<hta:application id=oHTA>
</head>
```

I now had access to the `<audio>` tag and used that as a solution

```html
<audio autoplay>
<source src="https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/animal-crossing-new-horizons-2020-switch-gamerip/pdjxvsymlc/3-02%20Get%20Ready%20for%20Your%20Flight!.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Note: The `hta:application` section is not supported in any mode higher than IE 9.  If you need any features of that section and also need to run in a mode higher than IE 9, there are workarounds, such as a two file HTA/HTM script or creating a VbsEdit HTML application.

Answer (score 1):

The bgsound tag is an Internet Explorer only tag, so this will not work in other browsers.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer