# Why is HTA with VB Script vs. CSS not working?

Tags: html, css, vbscript, hta

I wanted to code a little HTA file which looks in a specific folder if there are any jpg files and, if yes, it displays them. For that I used VBScript. Everything works fine so far. In a second step I wanted to add the possiblity to click on an image to enlarge/zoom it while using Java and/or CSS.

And here is the problem. I only get the HTA+VB Script working but **not** the CSS. When I add/remove the 16th line (`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`) I can get the CSS working but not the VBScript any more.

Why is this and how can I work with this?

I am forced to HTA and can not use PHP or similar.
But as soon as I want to add CSS or HTML stuff to my code, e.g. something like `document.GetElementsByClass` etc., it's not working any more. I add the line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` it works, but VBScript stops working.

My Code is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION
Id = "objHTA"
ApplicationName = "Test"
Scroll = "no"
SINGLEINSTANCE = "yes"
Icon = "Test.ico"
WindowState = "maximize"
>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<style>

div.beispiel1 img{
 transition: transform 0.2s;
}
div.beispiel1 img:hover {
 transform: scale(2.0, 2.0);
}

div.scroll-container {
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 316px;
}
div.scroll-container img {
  padding: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scroll-container">

<script type="text/vbscript">

Dim FolderPath
Dim objFSO
Dim objFolder
Dim colFiles
Dim objFile

FolderPath = "test\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
 If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "jpg" Then
  document.write "<img src='" & FolderPath & "\" & objFile.Name & "' width=384 height=216'>"
 End If
Next

</script>

</div>

<div class="beispiel1">
 <img src="test.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using VBEDit but it wont give me any errors. depening adding/remove line 16 it shows just a black screen and make my bottom css work - or on the other hand - it executes my vbscript but wont do any css.

Comment: Sorry I guess I am not a big help. I went step by step trough the code using VBSEdit and it wont show me any problems. I am not really sure how to check the browser debugger proberly :-/

Comment: Your declaration is invalid. HTAs run via MSHTML, not Chrome or any other modern engine. `IE=edge` does NOT mean "Edge browser". The `IE=edge` terminology pre-dates the Edge browser by many years. It means run at the highest IE-equivalent mode possible, which is, of course, 11. The highest mode that supports VBScript is 10, so you must change your declaration to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">`

Comment: @MisterJojo you understand what an HTA is right? There is no browser they will be running the HTA through `MSHTA.exe`.

Comment: Minor correction. Since you are trying to use the `hta:application` section, your declaration must be `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">` because 9 is the highest mode that supports that section.

Comment: See "Further background information on HTA document modes" in this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358044/15764378) for more details.

Comment: Since you are using VBSEdit, please note that you can up your game by saving your file as a `HTM` file and then get all the benefits of a proper VbsEdit HTML application, including the extensions for things like file open/save dialogs. It will also allow you to run in IE=10 mode and provide equivalents for most of the `hta:application` options. And finally, it will allow you to convert your project to a proper Exe (not just the self-extractor you'll get with an HTA and VbsEdit).

Comment: @LesFerch - Thank you alot! That worked perfect. I will read the concerning meta description to learn more about that.
So far really thank you :-)

Comment: Can I flag this thread somehow because my problem is solved?

Comment: Finally, I strongly advise using JScript instead of VBScript. That will allow you to use `IE=11` mode and not have to worry about your program failing on machines that do not have VBScript installed (which Microsoft warns is a near-future change).

Comment: I've answered everything in comments because this question will get flagged as a duplicate. I just saved you hours of doing the research and perhaps running in circles. Feel free to contact me directly. Look up the app WinSetView on GitHub. You'll find my contact info in the main manual.

Comment: @LesFerch is there a duplicate for this? If there is, flag it. Otherwise, add an answer.

Comment: `document.GetElementsByClass` is JavaScript, by the way, not HTML or CSS.

Comment: @TylerH pretty sure it was available through the MSHTML object model for both VBScript and JScript (`GetElementsByClassName()`).

Comment: @user692942 Possibly, but OP mentioned "*But as soon as I want to add CSS or HTML stuff to my code, e.g. something like document.GetElementsByClass etc*" indicating they were thinking it was HTML/CSS.

Comment: @LesFerch I suppose `chrome=1` is related to the (now obsoleted) [IE plug-in](https://download.cnet.com/google-chrome-frame/3000-12512_4-75159325.html). That probably wouldn't work with HTA, though.

Comment: @TylerH I'm pretty sure they were making the distinction between how it works /doesn't work with VBScript vs CSS, the `document.GetElementsByClassName()` being the VBScript.